# IIS showing Information from UNC drive

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, network-share

I'm trying to configure a website, which has to show some content from the local drive (that's the main site: http:/ /mysite/) but also it has to show some info stored on another server (on the same domain), which is on a UNC shared folder(\otherserver\cache).

When I configure my Virtual Directory to take its content from the UNC folder under the mian site (http:/ /mysite/remote_cache/) it doesn't show its content.

I gave everyone full control on the shared folder, and read / list directory to the virtual directory.

Any clue on how to configure this properly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the web site / app pool / IIS is running under the security context of a user who has access to network services, which is not the case by default.

You can also turn anonymous access off for the virtual directory and use delegation to access the shared folder, however that also requires setting up delegation trusts for the server.  You need to determine SPN's for your web service and add them to the machine account in Active Directory so that two-hop authentication can happen.  Basically, this allows IIS to impersonate the client that is connecting to it and "borrow" that user's credentials to connect to the remote share.  [Here is an Technet article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/523ae943-5e6a-4200-9103-9808baa00157.mspx?mfr=true) that talks about it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more? 

What do you mean by context? security context? 

What does setting up delegation consist of?

Comment: No problem, edited with more detail.